# Importing global variables into CoffeeScript scope

Tags: coffeescript

I've got the following simple Coffee file:

```
'use strict'

$("#subForm").submit()
```

This creates the JavaScript file:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  $("#subForm").submit();
}).call(this);
```

What I actually need is the equivalent of:

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  $("#subForm").submit();
})($);
```

How can I do this? Do I even need to do this?

This is for a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CoffeeScript is compiled  into an IIFE (and therefore is shielded against the global scope), all you need to do is use regular variable assignments at the beginning of your script as an alternative to global imports:

```coffeescript
'use strict'
$ = jQuery

$("#subForm").submit()
```

This compiles to:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var $;

  $ = jQuery;

  $("#subForm").submit();

}).call(this);
```

Having the global variables passed in as arguments to an enclosing IIFE wouldn't really provide any additional benefit beyond this as far as I can see.

The above works because `$` and `jQuery` are different identifiers, but if you wanted global imports that don't involve different names, you can use `@` to refer to the global object and do your "imports" that way:

```coffeescript
'use strict'
$ = jQuery
window = @
document = @document

$("#subForm").submit()
```